# SoapUI doesn't send out query string after "Post QueryString" is checked

Tags: rest, soapui

I tried to test RESTful web service by posting query parameters, however, after I checked "Post QueryString" check box, no parameters were send out with request

[image: before sending out request]

[image: The raw request, you can see no parameters go with request]

Can someone please tell me what is wrong? BTW, I am using version 4.5.1

Thanks a lot

Comment: Works for me. Tried it with versions 4.5.1, 4.6.0, and 5.1.0. Something else must be going on.

Answer (score 4):

I can't be sure, but increasing the Size of Raw Request to Show setting (which defaults to 10000) may help.

See: File / Preferences / UI Settings / Size of Raw Request to Show.

I set it to 100000, now I can see the POST query parameters in Raw mode, too.

(Also, credit goes [to SmartBear forum user olensmar](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=5440).)